# Using MultiAutoCompleteTextview which stores ids

Tags: android, spannable, multiautocompletetextview

In my app, I want to use a MultiAutoCompleteTextview to get an effect like Facebook mentioning. After I type '@', I want to get a dropdown list from which to select a person. This will show the person's name in the MACTextView.

> "Went to the cinema with John Doe"(What the user sees)-> "Went to the cinema with
>   [person:245]"(What I need to store)

How can I accomplish this? I know how to query my database and how to use the MultiAutoCompleteTextview. I just need help with differentiating between what's shown and what's stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Linkedin's [spyglass library](https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass). This provides a mention edittext which is very customizable. It works by setting spans for the mentions. When saving, I used getSpan() and replaced the spans with my tags.